# Using a base class and derived class in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to learn VB and am stuck on how to make my classes work.  I am trying to create an imaginary pet shop store. The Pet class is my base class and the Cat is my derived class. When trying to run this I have errors in debugging and do not know how to get my information to display correctly from the form once it is running.  If anyone has time to look at my code and offer advice on how to move forward, it would be much appreciated.

Pet:

```
Public Class Pet

    Private animal As String
        Private breed As String
        Private gender As String
    Private age As Integer


    Public Property AnimalType() As String
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            animal = Value
        End Set
        Get
            Return animal
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal animal As String)
        Me.animal = animal
    End Sub

    Public Property PetBreed() As String
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            breed = Value
        End Set
        Get
            Return Breed
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Breed As String)
        Me.breed = Breed
    End Sub

    Public Property PetGender() As String
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            gender = Value
        End Set
        Get
            Return Gender
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Gender As String)
        Me.gender = Gender
    End Sub

    Public Property PetAge() As Integer
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            age = Value
        End Set
        Get
            Return Age
```

Cat:

```
Public Class Cat
    Inherits Pet
End Class
```

PetShop:

```
Public Class PetShop
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim pet1 As New Pet("Boggle")
        Console.WriteLine("Animal: " & pet1.AnimalType & "Breed: " & pet1.PetBreed & "Gender: " & pet1.PetGender & "Age: " & pet1.PetAge)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `I have errors in debugging` it might help to tell us what those are.  Your cat class really doesnt add or make any changes to the base class.  Pet might have a MustOverride Speak method. Cat would override it and print Meow, while Dog would of course bark. Gender could be an Enum so that cant enter "I like pie".  Breed could also be an Enum  on the derived classes so that a different set could be entered for Dogs, Cats, Mugwai and Parakeets.  Age should be a ReadOnly property calculated from a DOB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example for you to see and examine.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim cat As Pet = New Cat("Hulk", "none - street cat", "male", #2/1/2005#)
        Console.WriteLine(cat.ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub


    Public MustInherit Class Pet

        Public Property Breed As String
        Public Property Gender As String
        Public Property DateOfBirth As DateTime

        Public ReadOnly Property Age As Integer
            Get
                Dim a As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year
                Return Convert.ToInt32(If(DateOfBirth.Date > DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(-a), --a, a))
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub New(breed As String, gender As String, dateOfBirth As DateTime)
            Me.Breed = breed
            Me.Gender = gender
            Me.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class Cat
        Inherits Pet

        Public Property Name As String

        Public Sub New(name As String, breed As String, gender As String, dateOfBirth As DateTime)
            MyBase.New(breed, gender, dateOfBirth)
            Me.Name = name
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("Name:{0}, Breed:{1}, Gender:{2}, DateOfBirth:{3:dd/MM/yyy}, Age:{4}", Name, Breed, Gender, DateOfBirth, Age)
        End Function

    End Class
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code as it stands is that you have three `Public Sub New`s all taking a `String` argument. When you use `Dim pet1 As New Pet("Boggle")`, is `"Boggle"` an `AnimalType`, a `Breed`, or a `Gender`? There's no way for the program to know what you mean. Using `Enum`s as @Plutonix suggested would help with this, although a single constructor such as `Public Sub New (ByVal animalType As String, ByVal breed As String, ByVal gender As String)` would help, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as *prprcupofcoffee* stated, you can't overload a method (create 2 or more methods with the same name) and use the same number & type of arguments.

So, if can always initialize your class using the 3 arguments, you can go with *prprcupofcoffee* answer. If you can't do that and want (for some reason) to be able initialize the class using any of the 3 arguments (I doubt that this is a requirement in your case tho), I once needed that in a class I was creating, and I created a workaround for this.. it can be applied to your class as the following:

```
Public Const sAnimal As String = "animal"
Public Const sBreed As String = "breed"
Public Const sGender As String = "pr"

Public Sub New(sIdentifier As String, sValue As String)
    CallByName(Me, sIdentifier, CallType.Set, sValue)
End Sub
```

So, now you can initialize the class like this:

```
    Dim myPuppy As New Pet(Pet.sAnimal, "puppy")
```

Hope that helps :)